Zabbix Trigger a senario Expression is invalid
im trying to create a trigger for checking if i got status check such as 200,404,500 in my web scenario that i created.
i tried to do this:
{:web.test.rspcode[API Status Check(the scenario name), Check API(the step name)].last()}=404
i go this error:
Invalid parameter "/1/expression": incorrect expression starting from "{:web.test.rspcode[API Status Check, Check API].last()}=404".
i tried to put in the section of  the host name, the host tamplate and so on but nothing
